# NullPointerException when calling service methode in a domain class methode

Tags: grails, grails-orm

According to Grails it should be possible to use a service within a domain class. But when I run the following simple example, the grails run-app fails with a NullPointerException: "Cannot invoke method test() on null object"

To reproduce use the following code pieces:

Bootstrap.groovy:

```
class BootStrap {
    def init = { servletContext ->
        new Test().test()
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

with the service:

```
@Transactional
class TestService {
    def test() {
    }
}
```

and the domain class:

```
class Test {
    def testService

    def test() {
        testService.test()
    }
}
```

This happens with Grails 3.2.9 and 3.3.0. Is this a Grails error or a GORM failure, not auto injecting the service into domain classes ?

SOLUTION:
For all wondering what the solution is (see answer from erichelgeson) using "static mapping = { autowire true }". But testing both solutions, I found that "static mapping ..." works in Grails 3.3.0 and in 3.2.9, hence setting it globally in application.yml did only work for Grails 3.2.9 but not in Grails 3.3.0 thou.

Comment: Try wrapping a withTransaction around the call so `Test.withTransaction{ new Test().test() }`. But I am going to be honest with you. This all seems very backwards you are using bootstrap to call a domain class that triggers a service. Call service directly in Bootstrap that is already transactional and does the record addition

Comment: Using "Test.withTransaction { .. }" does not help. I have tried it out.

Comment: Usage of "new Test().test()" in Bootstrap is just a simple way to force this error, without needing user interaction. It is  not meant to be anything else :-)

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of Grails (3.2.9+) have disabled autowire by default on domain classes for performance reasons. You can re-enable it:

per domain:

```
static mapping = {
   autowire true
}
```

or globally in application.yml/groovy

```
grails.gorm.autowire = true
```

See more @ http://gorm.grails.org/6.1.x/hibernate/manual/index.html
Section 1.2.9

Comment: Thanks, the trick with "static mapping = { autowire true }" did work in Grails 3.3.0 and in 3.2.9. But setting it globally in application.yml did only work for Grails 3.2.9 but not in Grails 3.3.0 thou.

Answer (score 0):

You could reenable autowiring per the previous suggestion, but there are performance implications to your whole application for that.  It may be worth it, if this is a common situation.

If this is a rare situation for you, you can also access a service as so, in a domain class:

```
Holders.applicationContext.serviceName.methodName()
```